# How do I print a Rust floating-point number with all available precision?

Tags: formatting, rust, cordic

I am implementing the CORDIC algorithm for the `sin` trigonometric function. In order to do this, I need to hardcode/calculate a bunch of arctangent values. Right now my function *seems* to work (as validated by Wolfram Alpha) to the precision that is printed, but I would like to be able to print all 32 bits of precision of my `f32`. How may I do that?

```
fn generate_table() {
    let pi: f32 = 3.1415926536897932384626;
    let k1: f32 = 0.6072529350088812561694; // 1/k
    let num_bits: uint = 32;
    let num_elms: uint = num_bits;
    let mul: uint = 1 << (num_bits - 2);

    println!("Cordic sin in rust");
    println!("num bits {}", num_bits);
    println!("pi is {}", pi);
    println!("k1 is {}", k1);

    let shift: f32 = 2.0;
    for ii in range(0, num_bits) {
        let ipow: f32 = 1.0 / shift.powi(ii as i32);
        let cur: f32 = ipow.atan();
        println!("table values {}", cur);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the [precision format specifier](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#syntax); a `.` followed by the number of decimal points of precision you'd like to see:

```
fn main() {
    let pi: f32 = 3.1415926536897932384626;
    let k1: f32 = 0.6072529350088812561694; // 1/k

    println!("pi is {:.32}", pi);
    println!("k1 is {:.32}", k1);
}
```

I chose 32, which is *more* than the number of decimal points in either of these `f32`s.

```
pi is 3.14159274101257324218750000000000
k1 is 0.60725295543670654296875000000000
```

Note that the values no longer match up; [floating point values are difficult](http://floating-point-gui.de/)! As mentioned in a comment, you may wish to [print as hexadecimal or even use your literals as hexadecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40030648/155423).

Comment: This answer won't work for small numbers (unless you adjust the format statement based on the size of the number.  :(

Comment: You need *I think* a precision of 51 to get all the digits for all `f32`'s, and then you need to trim trailing `0`'s *and* trailing `.`'s.

Comment: It is impossible, to display eg. the 1/k value with all digits, as required by the OP, if the last 6 digits have already been lost due to the wrong choice of floating-point type.

Answer (score 9):

Using the precision format specifier is the correct answer, but to print *all available precision*, simply refrain from specifying the number of digits to display:

```
// prints 1
println!("{:.}", 1_f64);

// prints 0.000000000000000000000000123
println!("{:.}", 0.000000000000000000000000123_f64);
```

This way, you will not truncate values nor will you have to trim excess zeros, and the display will be correct for all values, regardless of whether they are very large or very small.

[Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=4749a5434158bbd2379269fad6b028d7)

For completeness, the precision format specifier also supports a specifying a fixed precision (as per the accepted answer):

```
// prints 1.0000
println!("{:.4}", 1_f64);
```

as well as a precision specified at runtime (does not need to be `const`, of course):

```
// prints 1.00
const PRECISION: usize = 2;
println!("{:.*}", PRECISION, 1_f64); // precision specifier immediately precedes positional argument
```

Comment: This isn't entirely correct. `print!("{:.}", 1.0 + f64::EPSILON);print!("{:.20}", 1.0 + f64::EPSILON);` print different values

Answer (score 4):

> *This answer was written for Rust 0.12.0 and doesn't apply to Rust 1.x.*

---

You can use the [`to_string`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/f32/fn.to_string.html) function in `std::f32` (not to be confused with the [`to_string`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/to_string/trait.ToString.html#tymethod.to_string) method):

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", std::f32::to_string(unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<i32, f32>(1) }));
    println!("{}", std::f32::to_string(unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<i32, f32>(16) }));
    println!("{}", std::f32::to_string(std::f32::MIN_POS_VALUE));
    println!("{}", std::f32::to_string(std::f32::MAX_VALUE));
    println!("{}", std::f32::to_string(std::f32::consts::PI));
}
```

Output:

```
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140129852294921875
0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022420775890350341796875
0.000000000000000000000000000000000000011754944324493408203125
340282368002860660002286082464244022240
3.1415927410125732421875
```

Comment: hmm, "very large" seems a bit strange, it would be nice to print what accuracy i actually have, which if i understand your answer would be more like  `{:.31f}` i wonder if that magic number could be pulled from the fact that i am reading a `f32` ?

Comment: I found something better; see my edit. (Edit: I didn't see Arjan's answer yet when I made this edit.)

Comment: With this method how would i know that i have 32bits of precision if i was printing the exact value of `1` in `f32`?

Comment: You can't relate the precision of a decimal number with the precision of a binary number. Maybe you want to print the float in binary or hex, instead? See [`to_str_hex`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/f32/fn.to_str_hex.html) and [`to_str_radix_special`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/f32/fn.to_str_radix_special.html).

Answer (score 3):

> *This answer was written for Rust 0.12.0 and doesn't apply to Rust 1.x.*

---

You can use [`std::f32::to_string`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/std/f32/fn.to_string.html) to print all the digits.

```
use std::f32;

fn main() {
    let pi: f32 = 3.1415926536897932384626;
    let k1: f32 = 0.6072529350088812561694; // 1/k

    println!("pi is {}", f32::to_string(pi));
    println!("k1 is {}", f32::to_string(k1));
}
```

Output:

```
pi is 3.1415927410125732421875
k1 is 0.607252979278564453125
```

Comment: could you look at my comment to Francis Gagné and see if your solution addresses showing only the digits that we actually know we have?

Answer (score -1):

IMHO there is no way around the bigdecimal crate, if you want to store floating-point numbers with high precision, because you need all the digits like the OP:
`0.6072529350088812`**`561694`**

```
use bigdecimal::BigDecimal;

fn main() {
    let pi = BigDecimal::parse_bytes(b"3.1415926536897932384626", 10);
    let k1 = BigDecimal::parse_bytes(b"0.6072529350088812561694", 10);  // 1/k

    println!("pi is {pi:?}");
    println!("k1 is {k1:?}");
}
```

*gets:*
`pi is Some(BigDecimal("3.1415926536897932384626"))`
`k1 is Some(BigDecimal("0.6072529350088812561694"))`