# Rust float formatted as integer by generics

Tags: generics, rust

I have the following Rust code:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point<T, U> {
    x: T,
    y: U
}

impl<T: std::fmt::Display, U: std::fmt::Display> Point<T, U> {
    fn print(&self) {
        println!("{} {}", &self.x, &self.y );
    }
}

impl<X1, Y1> Point<X1, Y1> {
    fn mixup<X2, Y2>(self, other: Point<X2, Y2>) -> Point<X1, Y2> {
        Point {
            x: self.x,
            y: other.y,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let integer = Point {x: 1, y:2};
    let float = Point{x: 2.0, y:3.0};

    let floaty = integer.mixup(float);

    println!("{:?}", floaty); // output: Point { x: 1, y: 3.0 } - OK
    floaty.print(); // output: 1 3 - NOT OK
}
```

Why does `floaty.print()` coerce `3.0` to `3`? Is there anything wrong with how the `print` method is implemented?

Comment: Note that `println!("{}", 3.0f64)` also prints `3` so this is just how the `Display` implementation of floats works.

Comment: If you use `{:?}` in your `print()` function, you should see the decimal point.

Comment: `"{:?}"` marker formats arguments in `Debug` mode, `"{}"` marker formats arguments in `Display` mode: and their implementations: https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/fmt/float.rs.html#193, for other kinds of formats you can check this link: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#traits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Minimized example:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("{} {:?}", 3.0, 3.0);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=413c46337c23afbd9ad33a9533c2db40))

This prints `3 3.0`, i.e. floats which don't have a fractional part are formatted via `Display` as integers. That's not something wrong with `print` function - just the fact that `Display` implies human-readable output, and for human-readable output it is chosen to print integers where possible.

Comment: Additional remark: if you want a specific precision shown, `println` expects you to specify that explicitly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26576889/how-do-i-print-a-rust-floating-point-number-with-all-available-precision