# Pass in int to function and return float Rust

Tags: rust, casting

I am very new to Rust and am trying to dip my toes in it a bit and ran into issues trying to work with integers and floats. I am trying to figure out how to take in an integer as a variable for a recursive logarithm function that will return a float. The issue is that my return value is still an integer.

```
fn log(x: f64,b: f64) -> f64 {    
    if x < b {
        return 0.0;
    }

    let result = 1.0 + log(x / b, b);

    return result;
}

fn main() {
    let test_num1: i64 = 3;
    let test_num2: i64 = 11;

    let y: f64 = log(test_num2 as f64, test_num1 as f64);
    println!("\nDEBUGGING RESULT = {}\n", y as f64);
}
```

However my code outputs this:

```
DEBUGGING RESULT = 2
```

but am expecting something along the lines of 2.182...

What is the proper way to allow for integers to be manipulated and assigned as floats? Any help is much appreciated!

Update: 
The error was in my code :) in the log() function specifically. Sebastian pointed out where the logic is a bit messed up!

Comment: Hello, try `format!("{:.2}", https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26576889/how-do-i-print-a-rust-floating-point-number-with-all-available-precision

Comment: Everything here works as intended. `y` should be equal to `2.0` and it is (you can try `assert_eq!(y, 2.0)` to see for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but am expecting something along the lines of 2.182...

Your expectation is just wrong. Consider what your `log` function might do: either it returns 0, or it returns 1 plus whatever the recursive call returns. Therefore, it can only ever return whole numbers (and specifically, it returns how often you can divide x by b before x becomes smaller, which is 2 in your test case).

Comment: Thank you! This made me realize the logic was messed up!

Comment: The weird part for me is that the Display implementation for `f64` doesn't print it as `2.0`